# multi sites with apache under same domain

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm using apache server and PHP,
I've just done a cms, and now I would like to provide some demos at different URLs,
BUT within the same domain, for example `mydomain.com`.

Something like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/demo1

http://www.mydomain.com/demo2
...

If those were the corresponding real paths on my server:

```
/myserver/cms/demo1
/myserver/cms/demo2
```

I don't want to change my cms code to achieve this (if possible)

The first solution I thought of was buy a domain for each demo, and use
Virtual Hosting to map a demo to a domain. That would do exactly what I want,
but that would be too expensive...

With Alias directive,

```
Alias /demo1/ /myserver/cms/demo1
```

is almost perfect, but I still got the problem that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable is modified from `/` to `/demo1`, which unfortunately makes my cms confuse.

I would need a truly unobstrusive way of doing this, like with virtual hosts.

If you've faced that problem too, I would like to hear how you dealed with it.

Answer (score 0):

I use sub-domains (demo1.example.com, demo2.example.com, etc.) with a wildcard DNS entry (*.example.com always resolves to the same host) so that I don't have to make any DNS changes, I only have to add more virtual hosts to Apache.

Works well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself::

If you were interested by the topic, here is how I did ( and it worked, thanks to gravyface, ):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.jetdemo
    ServerAlias test.jetdemo
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Mac/projets/jetsites/demo/ecommerce/store1/application/www"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jetdemo
    ServerAlias *.jetdemo
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Mac/projets/jetsites/demo/" 
</VirtualHost>
```

I've noticed that the order of the virtual hosts' bloc is important:
the bloc containing the wildcard ( ServerAlias *.jetdemo )
has to be the last one, otherwise it won't work!, or you'll have to remove the wildcard
( ServerAlias jetdemo ).